# iFrame interactions not working properly in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, wkwebview

iFrame interactions are not working in WKWebView. The same iFrames works on UIWebView and Safari.

What have I done so far:

1. Debugging webpage with Safari Web Inspector, Console does not display any message relevant to this issue
2. XCode Debugger does not show any message relevant to this issue
3. Found a similar post about the iFrame problem inside WKWebView https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/179394#179394

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: For my case, just Inject JS via Objective C: window.addEventListener('touchstart', {});